# How can I exclude certain dates (e.g., weekends) from time series plots?

Tags: python, altair

In the following example, I'd like to exclude weekends and plot `Y` as a straight line, and specify some custom frequency for major tick labels since they would be a "broken" time series (e.g., every Monday, a la `matplotlib`'s `set_major_locator`).

How would I do that in Altair?

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

index = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-01-31', freq='B')
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.arange(len(index)), index=index, columns=['Y'])

alt.Chart(df.reset_index()).mark_line().encode(
    x='index',
    y='Y'
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick way to do that is to specify the axis as an ordinal field. This would produce a very ugly axis, with the hours specified for every tick. To change that, I add a column to the dataframe with a given label. I also added the `grid`, as by default it is removed for an ordinal encoding, and set the `labelAngle` to 0.

```
df2 = df.assign(label=index.strftime('%b %d %y'))

alt.Chart(df2).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X('label:O', axis=alt.Axis(grid=True, labelAngle=0)),
    y='Y:Q'
)
```

[image: altair-chart-ordinal-axis]

Beware that it would remove any missing point. So, maybe you want to add a tooltip. This is discussed in the documentation [here](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/encoding.html#effect-of-data-type-on-axis-scales).
You can also play with `labelOverlap` in the axis setting depending of hat you want.

---

To customize the axis, we can build one up using `mark_text` and bring back the grid with `mark_rule` and a custom dataframe. It does not necessarily scale up well, but it can give you some ideas.

```
df3 = df2.loc[df2.index.dayofweek == 0, :].copy()
df3["Y"] = 0

text_chart = alt.Chart(df3).mark_text(dy = 15).encode(
    x=alt.X('label:O', axis = None),
    y=alt.Y('Y:Q'),
    text=alt.Text('label:O')
)

tick_chart = alt.Chart(df3).mark_rule(color='grey').encode(
    x=alt.X('label:O', axis=None),
)

line_chart = alt.Chart(df2).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X('label:O', axis=None, scale=alt.Scale(rangeStep=15)),
    y='Y:Q'
)
text_chart + tick_chart + line_chart
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great!  Any idea if we can control exactly where the labels for x-axis values are located?  So, every Monday, for example?

Comment: I don't know if it is possible. As it is an ordinal scale, you cannot control the ticks, as every point in the data is a tick. You could layer a chart with a point on each Monday maybe, to draw attention to the mondays ?

Comment: I edited the answer with kind of a hack to customize the axis